# Politics - Employer put a sign up in our yard for someone I don't support

Tags: employer-relations, politics

I work at a small office with about half a dozen people. My employer just put a sign in the yard supporting someone running for City Council. I don't support this person and don't like that the sign is there.

I'm thinking about mentioning this to my boss, but I'm not sure how much it matters to me. I don't know what should be done in a case like this. I feel politics shouldn't be invading our office but I don't know what I'm basing that on. What is the best way to approach my boss about taking down the sign?

Comment: I think when he already put the sign in the yard, your boss already should knew and supported that.

Comment: Just the six people, there is no larger company.

Comment: His yard or your yard? If its your yard then take it down. If its his yard (the company yard) then its none of your business. He is expressing a company view (probably to attract more customers). As a member of a sophisticated society you have be able to understand that other people have different views from you and that should not affect your day to day dealings with them.

Comment: The company's yard is not the boss's personal yard. I would think that these sorts of distinctions are what make a society “sophisticated”…

Comment: By way of comparison, in Germany, the sign would be considered illegal: “(…) The employer and the works council shall refrain from activities that interfere with operations or imperil the peace in the establishment. They shall refrain from any activity within the establishment in promotion of a political party; (…)” (Works Constitution Act, Section 74)

Comment: Well, if the boss owns the company, then it's his yard. If the boss is not the owner and the company and the owner doesn't object, then it's the same outcome as if the boss owns the company. Signs in the yard are just opinions - the only thing that counts is the vote that's cast.

Comment: Make a calendar entry to bring it up in 4 months. After the elections are done and past, take a short meeting with your boss and let him know that his displaying of political point of view materials on Company property was disconcerting to you. Don't "take a stand" on the actual politics, just respectfully ask that he keep his campaigning to his personal property. You might even (if you can deal with a little white lie) tell him you supported the same candidate, but still don't like the politics at work. If he balks, let him know you just wanted him to know your feelings and leave it at that.

Comment: You might even raise the point that by showing support for one candidate/party, he effectively shut his business to supporters of the other side, costing him potential business. Today's world is so divided that, considering the poor state of the economy, small companies would not be well served to take a stand like that.

Comment: There's a reason that people say you should never talk religion and politics unless you know the people well and are "like-minded". Because no amount of discussion will change the other person's opinion and both people leave thinking the other is ignorant and they'll both leave thinking less of the other. It's your boss's property, not yours. Unless you want your boss to think you are ignorant, which isn't good for your career, then don't discuss religion and politics with them. Expressing your disapproval of the sign is certainly discussing politics.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I'm thinking about mentioning this to my boss, but I'm not sure how
>   much it matters to me. I don't know what should be done in a case like
>   this. I feel politics shouldn't be invading our office but I don't
>   know what I'm basing that on. What is the best way to approach my boss
>   about taking down the sign?

In a larger organization, the answer might be different. But in small businesses like these, you are typically subject to the owner's choices.

If it's not really that important to you (and that's the way it seems based on what you wrote), you are probably best off by just ignoring it. Nobody will assume that you support this candidate just because the company owner does. As long as you aren't forced to contribute to the candidate, stuff envelopes, or make phone calls on the candidate's behalf or such, it doesn't seem like much of an invasion.

If you feel strongly enough, and your boss is the company owner, you could bring it up. But don't expect the owner to take the sign down because you don't approve - it's her/his business, not yours. If this is something you simply cannot tolerate, you may to find an employer whose political views match yours.

My wife works for a 6-person office. The political views of her boss and my wife are pretty much opposite. She has learned to mostly avoid political talk in the office. When her boss and another co-worker start talking about politics, she just leaves the room.

I suppose you can always put an opposing candidate's bumper sticker on your car and park it so that the sticker is visible.

Comment: I don't think it's so much about opposing political views as it is about overt political expression in the workplace.

Comment: Unfortunately true.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Sounds like I'm in a pretty similar situation to your wife. I'll probably just leave this alone like I would if they were just talking about politics. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 4):

If the yard is the employer's and there are no city ordinances or lease rules against this then your only real avenue for any change is through your boss. I wouldn't specifically ask to have "that" sign removed as that would give the impression it's only an issue because you disagree with the individual candidate or measure and not politics at work conceptually.

I would recommend keeping it nice and level and express "concern" that bringing politics into the work place will create a negative effect on productivity. There is also the possibility it could create a hostile work environment for those with opposing views.

So yeah, typically politics + office = bad. (unless politics is actually your line of business)

Comment: I would also add that, depending on the type of business, it could potentially put off customers who might oppose those views.

Comment: @DavidK: Or it could be put there explicitly to attract more customers if you understand your customer base.

Answer (score 3):

Your company probably pays taxes, so the owners of that company have a right to campaign. If I drove by and saw the sign, I wouldn't assume that all employees endorse this person.

I've probably held different political views than most of the people I've worked for and would only have a discussion in this area if I had a very strong working relationship and felt the owners were capable of accepting a different opinion. Otherwise, I would not discuss politics with my boss.